# Route of Controller works only on lowercase

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I have a controller, i removed all the data from it leaving a simple Index action with a parameterless view return. The thing is the following, i have a definition of my controller

```
[AuthorizeExtension]
public class TasksController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext( );

    public string CurrentUserId => User.Identity.GetUserId( );

    // GET: Tasks
    public ActionResult Index( )
    {
        var data = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData( HttpContext );

        return View(  );
    }
}
```

Once upon a time i could access it by **localhost/Tasks** .Now if i try the same url, i get redirected to the login view (that's what **authorizeExtension** does if i'm not logged in) while i am logged in, but it does work on lower case accessing **localhost/tasks**, same goes for sub pages index,create,details etc. Other pages work while this one doesn't. I also tried duplicating it with a new controller with same views, it works, but if i do the following

```
[AuthorizeExtension]
[RoutePrefix("Tasks")]
public class EmptyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext( );

    public string CurrentUserId => User.Identity.GetUserId( );

    // GET: Tasks
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index( )
    {
        var data = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData( HttpContext );

        return View( );
    }
}
```

again i get redirected. I have attached a print screen within the **authorizationExtensionm** with the **HttpContext.User** I'm loosing my identity. [image: HttpContext.User]

Comment: I haven't found a fix and i changed the controller name, was trying to avoid it because of all the ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after hitting the the issue the second time, it was actually a misplacement of keys in the database, going back to a working migration did the trick.